# designing a schema in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Imagine I have two schema: categories and products. Now I need a third schema called lists. The admins can create a list with multiple categories and the categories in turn will have multiple products.

Also one category can be in multiple lists and one product can be in any number of categories. I always to create a schema using the below way.

```
lists: {
   _id: '1',
   name: 'list 1',
   categories: [{
       categoryId: '201',
       products: [
           {
              productId: '301',
              name: 'product 1'
           },
           {
              productId: '302',
              name: 'product 2'
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       categoryId: '202',
       products: [
           {
              productId: '302',
              name: 'product 2'
           },
           {
              productId: '304',
              name: 'product 4'
           }
       ]           
   }]
}
```

The problem with this is say if I have to remove a product from category I have to loop through all the products and find the product and delete it. I have to do the same when I need to query only one product or one category. Is there a better way to create the lists schema?

Comment: Scheme tag is for lisp language.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to loop through the results if you perform an `aggregate` which will `unwind` your arrays. Look at that query :

```
db.device.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$categories"
},{
    "$unwind": "$categories.products"
}])
```

will transform your array into json object :

```
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "list 1", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "201", "products" : { "productId" : "301", "name" : "product 1" } } }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "list 1", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "201", "products" : { "productId" : "302", "name" : "product 2" } } }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "list 1", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "202", "products" : { "productId" : "302", "name" : "product 2" } } }
{ "_id" : "1", "name" : "list 1", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "202", "products" : { "productId" : "304", "name" : "product 4" } } }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "list 2", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "201", "products" : { "productId" : "303", "name" : "product 3" } } }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "list 2", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "201", "products" : { "productId" : "304", "name" : "product 4" } } }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "list 2", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "202", "products" : { "productId" : "302", "name" : "product 2" } } }
{ "_id" : "2", "name" : "list 2", "categories" : { "categoryId" : "202", "products" : { "productId" : "304", "name" : "product 4" } } }
```

Combine some matches to your liking and you got your specific result easily. The following will give you only records containing the specific `categories.categoryId` & `categories.products.productId` :

```
db.device.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$categories"
},{
    "$unwind": "$categories.products"
}, {
    $match: {
        "categories.categoryId": "201",
        "categories.products.productId": "301"
    }
}])
```

which gives you :

```
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "list 1",
    "categories": {
        "categoryId": "201",
        "products": {
            "productId": "301",
            "name": "product 1"
        }
    }
}
```

You can add a `$group` key to group by `_id` or anything else. Look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

To drop an item of your subarray `products`, no need to loop through results too, with an `update` request and a `pull`, you can find exactly what you want in your array and remove it in one request.

In the following request, I use a `pull` with a positional parameters defined by the result of `elemMatch` since you have an array inside another array :

```
db.device.update({
    'categories': {
        '$elemMatch': {
            categoryId: '201'
        }
    },
    _id: '1'
}, {
    $pull: {
        'categories.$.products': {
            'productId': '301'
        }
    }
});
```

The query above will remove only the element containing `productId` 301 for `categoryId` 201 and for element matchin `_id=1`

Check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can design the schema like you would normally do with SQL database if you  don't want to get `categories` and `products` with your lists.  Something like this:

```
List
      {
           '_id':1,
           'name': 'groceries'  
        }

Category
    {
      '_id':1,
      'listId': 1,
      'name': 'Cereal'
    }
Product
    {
      '_id': 1,
      'name': 'Weetbix',
      'categoryId':1
    }
```

Doing this way will help you manage data at ease.